# Dual Booting With Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

Im looking to dual boot my computer with Windows 10. Im currently running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. How would I go about doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Is Ubuntu installed in UEFI or BIOS? And is system UEFI or BIOS?  And then gpt or MBR? Post this: `sudo parted -l`. What brand/model system?

Answer (score 2):

There are many many guides on doing this and it's not actually that difficult. Here is one guide

http://news.softpedia.com/news/how-to-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-linux-500635.shtml

When I dual booted Windows 10 and Ubuntu, I had to disable secureboot in the BIOS and I also had to disable fast resume from within windows. Also, I had to install Windows first so that grub included Windows in the boot list. (Windows will not include Ubuntu !)

However, I am totally Windows free these days except for an XP virtualbox that I use to run the odd program that is Windows only.

Hope this helps.